# C++/OpenGL, drawing random char to screen

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl

**(using C++, OpenGL/GLUT, Xcode, OSX)**

I'm looking for help in drawing random characters to the screen.
I've separated the task into 2 parts...

(1) I am able to pick a random UPPER_CASE letter using the following:

```
    int launchCode1_random = rand() % 26;
    char c1 = (char)(launchCode1_random+65);
    cout << c1 << "\n";
```

(2) And I can draw strings in OpenGL using the following:

```
    string launchCode1 = "thing";
    void * fontlaunchCode1 = GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15;
    for (string::iterator i = launchCode1.begin(); i != launchCode1.end(); ++i)
    {
        char c = *i;
        glutBitmapCharacter(fontlaunchCode1, c);
    }
```

... What I would like to write in step 2 above, however, is:

```
    string launchCode1 = c1;
```

In doing so, I receive the following error: "No viable conversion from 'char' to 'string'. That makes sense to me on the surface. But I don't fully understand why or how. And if there is an alternative workaround that I'm not seeing, I would love to hear your thoughts on the subject.

edit.....

Here's the final, working code with Pubby's help:

```
    int launchCode1_random = rand() % 26;
    char c1 = (char)(launchCode1_random+65);
    cout << c1 << "\n";

    string launchCode1 (1, c1);
    void * fontlaunchCode1 = GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15;
    for (string::iterator i = launchCode1.begin(); i != launchCode1.end(); ++i)
    {
        char c = *i;
        glutBitmapCharacter(fontlaunchCode1, c);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to construct a `std::string` from a character you can do this:

```
string launchCode1(1, c1);
```

Using this constructor:

```
string( size_type count, 
        CharT ch, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

I don't fully understand what you're doing though. Why even bother with `std::string` if all you want is a single character? Just do this:

```
int launchCode1_random = rand() % 26;
char c = (char)(launchCode1_random+65);
glutBitmapCharacter(fontlaunchCode1, c);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pubby. That works wonderfully. Here's my updated code: '        int launchCode1_random = rand() % 26;
        char c1 = (char)(launchCode1_random+65);
        cout << c1 << "\n";
        
        string launchCode1 (1, c1);
        void * fontlaunchCode1 = GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15;
        for (string::iterator i = launchCode1.begin(); i != launchCode1.end(); ++i)
        {
            char c = *i;
            glutBitmapCharacter(fontlaunchCode1, c);
        }
'

Comment: @kropcke You're welcome. Edit your updated code into the question.

Comment: This is part of a game that I'm working on, and I'm adding some visual fluff to the experience by having random letters appear onscreen at specific times and places. Kind of 'matrix-y'. Thank you again for your help - I sincerely appreciate it (hopefully you can read this via the comment formatting. Sincerely, kropcke.

Comment: @kropcke A suggestion I will add is to keep your tasks separated. Have a function `char random_uppercase()` for the first task and `void draw_string(std::string)` for the second. A `void draw_char(char)` might be helpful too.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Pubby, I will try to do that. I'm pretty inexperienced, so I appreciate your feedback. It is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your problem but still nice to know: You need this line of code:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
```

before all this

```
int launchCode1_random = rand() % 26;
char c1 = (char)(launchCode1_random+65);
cout << c1 << "\n";
```

Otherwise you'll just end up with the same random character over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up Nilzone-, clearly the effect would be lost otherwise - heheh. Thank you very much for your help - I appreciate it. Sincerely, kropcke

Comment: This isn't exactly right.  You'd get the exact same sequence of characters on each execution, but it wouldn't be the same character repeated.